# Angular2 component not rendering

Tags: angular

I created a plunker, but I don't seem to be able to make it work, when looking in chrome console, there is an error I can't figure out why...

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

https://plnkr.co/edit/a7F616WCoKbSGXzlYGsM?p=preview

Anyway, my question was not about plunker, it was to create the exemple of my bug.

I have a component I want to use in another component, I imported it and added it to the directives: [] of the component decorator and it does not render...

The component is line-list.component, its selector is gb-line-list and I'm trying to use it in this file app/area-list.component.ts.

I feel I'm not clear at all, but I can't make my plunker exemple work properly.

**area-detail.component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';

import {LineListComponent} from './line-list.component';
import {Area} from './area.interface';
import {LineService} from './lines.service';

@Component({
    selector: '[gb-area-detail]',
    directives: [LineListComponent],
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="area">
            <h2>{{area.name}} area</h2>
            <gb-line-list [areaId]="area.id"></gb-line-list>
        </div>
    `
})
export class AreaDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    private area: Area;

    constructor(
        private _lineService: LineService,
        private _routeParams: RouteParams){}

    ngOnInit() {
        let id = +this._routeParams.get('id');

        this._lineService.getArea(id)
            .then(area => this.area = area);
    }

}
```

**line-list.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from 'angular2/core';

import {LineService} from './lines.service';
import {Line} from './line.interface';

@Component({
    selector: '[gb-line-list]',
    template: `
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="#line of lines">{{line.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    `
})
export class LineListComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() areaId: number;

   private lines: Line[];

   constructor (
       private _lineService: LineService) {}

   getLines() {
       this._lineService.getLines(this.areaId)
        .then(lines => this.lines = lines);
   }

   ngOnInit() {
       this.getLines();
   }
}
```

edit: 
the real problem is define in there
[Component not rendering properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36191417/component-not-rendering-properly)

Comment: Oh and when I'm in my environment, I get no error in chrome'S console...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue in your imports. In the plnkr, in every file where you import `LineService` you import it from `./lines.service`, but that file contains a Component, not a service, therefore you're importing something undefined.

This line for example

```
import {LineService} from './lines.service';
```

And in your `lines.service.ts` file you have this

```
export class LineListComponent implements OnInit {}
```

You have no `LineService` in that file.

The error is not really helpful because of an error in the error message itself (yes, kind of confusing). The error message should actually look like this

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: undefined

There's a [pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7729) to fix that problem and make the error message to be more helpful.

When you fix that, you'll see that you'll get this error message

> Route config should contain exactly one "component", "loader", or "redirectTo" property.

That's because of the same above. You confused your classes in your imports. For example you have this import

```
import {AreaListComponent} from './area-list.component';
```

But in `area-list.component` you defined the `AreaDetailComponent` class.

You're just importing the classes from the incorrect files, you defined class A in file B, and class B in file A.

Here's your [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/joCqAVj2A2TecWyTCBuw?p=preview) with the original error reported fixed.

Comment: wow thanks, I was very confused... I fixed the plunker, now my real problem is happening