# Component not rendering properly

Tags: angular

I created a plunker to show what the problem is.

https://plnkr.co/edit/a7F616WCoKbSGXzlYGsM?p=preview

I have a component I want to use in another component, I imported it and added it to the directives: [] of the component decorator and it does not render...

The component is line-list.component, its selector is gb-line-list and I'm trying to use it in this file app/area-list.component.ts.

the first page shows a list of areas, when clicking on one area, I want to show the detail of this area with a list of line. That's that list of line that is not rendering...

area-detail.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';
import {LineListComponent} from './line-list.component';
import {Area} from './area.interface';
import {LineService} from './lines.service';

@Component({
    selector: '[gb-area-detail]',
    directives: [LineListComponent],
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="area">
            <h2>{{area.name}} area</h2>
            <gb-line-list [areaId]="area.id"></gb-line-list>
        </div>
    `
})
export class AreaDetailComponent implements OnInit {
    private area: Area;

    constructor(
        private _lineService: LineService,
        private _routeParams: RouteParams){}

    ngOnInit() {
        let id = +this._routeParams.get('id');

        this._lineService.getArea(id)
            .then(area => this.area = area);
    }

}
```

line-list.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from 'angular2/core';

import {LineService} from './lines.service';
import {Line} from './line.interface';

@Component({
    selector: '[gb-line-list]',
    template: `
        <ul>


          <li *ngFor="#line of lines">{{line.name}}</li>
        </ul>
    `
})
export class LineListComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() areaId: number;

   private lines: Line[];

   constructor (
       private _lineService: LineService) {}

   getLines() {
       this._lineService.getLines(this.areaId)
        .then(lines => this.lines = lines);
   }

   ngOnInit() {
       this.getLines();
   }
}
```

Comment: You missed the plnkr :P

Comment: yes, I realized it haha

Comment: the selector selector: '[gb-line-list]'  is attribute selector but you are using it as an element selector. Here is  [you plunker fixed](https://plnkr.co/edit/EbDwX0De64yUJ9pkAM8C?p=preview),  changed line 14 of area-detail.component.ts

Comment: @Abdulrahman is there a way to use it as an element instead of an attributd?

Comment: Yes, just change the selector definition to : selector: 'gb-line-list', without brackets

Comment: @Abdulrahman if you solved it make it an answer :D

Comment: @Abdulrahman good! it's working, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are defining the selector as an attribute selector     `selector: '[gb-line-list]'` but you are trying to render the component using an element selector `<gb-line-list [areaId]="area.id"></gb-line-list>`.

You have two choices:
- Either change the selector to `selector: 'gb-line-list'`
- Or change the element to `<div gb-line-list [areaId]="area.id"></div>`

Finally, you might benefit from [Angular Cheat Sheet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/cheatsheet.html)